# How to center elements in div container

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck trying to center the  and

within the   , I tried text-align
margin:0 auto;  ,,, I think it has something to do with having body {margin:0}
P.S: Just practicing trying to copy a Template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Acme Web Design Home</title>
        <style>
            header h1{
                 margin-top: 50px; float:left; padding:20px 0 20px 20px;
                 font-size:40px;
                 }
            header {background-color:#35424a;border-bottom:orange solid 5px;color: white;
            height:150px;width: 100%;color:white;}
            ul   {float: right;}
            body {margin:0}
            ul li {display: inline-block;padding: 30px;font-size:30px;margin:35px 0px 80px 0px;}
            header a {text-decoration:none;color:white}
            .container  {margin:auto; width: 90%;}
            .showcase{margin: 0 auto;width:90%;text-align: center;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
          <h1 id="Logo">Acme Web Design</h1>
          
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
            </ul>             
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div class="Showcase">
            <h1>Affordable Professional Web Design</h1>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eu luctus ipsum, rhoncus semper magna. Nulla nec magna sit amet sem interdum condimentum.
           </p>
        </div>
        <div class="SubForm">
            <h2>Subscribe to our News letter</h2>
            <form>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your Email..">
                <button type="button">Subscribe</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What `div` do you want to center?

Comment: The showcase div ,  want the <h1> and <p> to be centered within it

Comment: `{ display:flex; align-content:center; align-items:center; }`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Your `<body>` should come after `</head>` with nothing in between

Answer (score 1):

after spending some time on this I used inspector tools and figured out that my text was wrapping around the float from the  and that is why the text seemed it won't center in the page, had to rewrite everything poorly done :/

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```css
.showcase{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:90%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, centering elements can be done 2 ways (well, more). You can either use the `<center>` tag or use css:

```
<style>
.showcase {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
min-height: 300px;
padding-left: 30%;
padding-right: 30%;
padding-top: 30%;
padding-bottom: 30%; /* Change this to suit you :) */
}
</style>
<div class="showcase">
<p> Content </p>
</div>
```

use `padding: /* % */` to move elements inside of a section

Good luck with your project :)

Have a great day